# Restrict changing of worksheet name

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365.
One of my requirement is to restrict the user from changing the sheet name.
However they should be able to change the contents of the sheet. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Office-js doesn't yet support workbook level protection. Only worksheet and range protection is available. Once the workbook protection API is provided you should be able to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Correction  - I was asking about the worksheet name in a workbook. Can i have the worksheet protected but can edit the range inside the worksheet ?

Comment: The only way to protect the worksheet name from being edited is to protect the entire workbook -- which OfficeJs currently doesn't offer. Any level of protection at the worksheet itself doesn't protect the renaming itself.

Comment: The `AllowEditRanges` API is not yet supported - so currently it is not possible to only allow certain part of the range on a protected range.